# Limit htaccess to tld or append location to end

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https

For a site with shopping cart we have https working on the domain.com/shop-2/cart location. When a user leaves the cart to other links on the site they are still sitting in HTTPS mode which is slow and actually gives an error b/c items on other pages are not setup for https connections.

I've been able to successfully detect https requests and redirect them to http but it's not appending the current user location (ie https:// domain.com/test should be http:// domain.com/test but comes out http:// domain.com). I've appended the redirect code I'm working with so far. I'm trying to get it to leave shop-2 alone since I want an SSL connection there.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop-2
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

We're working on a Rackspace Cloud Sites server hence the ENV:HTTPS. HTTPS alone doesn't actually detect that we're on HTTPS because of some proxy layer on a different IP.

The spaces are in the domain examples b/c I don't have enough rep to post more than 2 links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`$` is the signifier for a group, not `%`.

Comment: that makes it append the url properly but it's redirecting shop-2 to the home page instead of letting is stay on SSL.

Comment: I believe you also need to remove the leading / in the second condition. (RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^shop-2)

Comment: I also had to flip the order of the RewriteCond arguments.